# Is Facebook Send Dialog the solution to send a simple text based message to a user rather than link?

Tags: facebook, iframe, dialog, message

I am building a Facebook tab page and would like to have a link to contact a user (the tab page owner, myself) via a simple HTML link so that a user clicks the 'send a message' link and it opens a dialog with the recipient already attached to the message. This was instead of my previous solution of a basic mailto: anchor link but realised it would be much better to integrate this functionality inside Facebook.

I looked at the Facebook Send Dialog (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) which seemed like the perfect solution. On further inspection it seems it is more geared up for sending/sharing links rather than just a simple message. I tried removing the *link* and *name* properties to simplify the functionality, but this created an error as it seems like it has to have a pre populated link?

There must be a really simple solution to this that someone can point out? Perhaps I am missing something quite obvious here!

Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the send dialog is probally your best solution for this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

from jssdk you could use feed dialog which can be set up to send to individual user, or pages you own.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/  using the to parameter.

---

the below sample does require Javascript SDK - you can get here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

```
<javascript>
            function feedthis() {
             FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
            message: '',
            //caption: 'This is the Caption value.',
            //name: 'Testing JS feed dialog on ShawnsSpace',
            //link: 'http://shawnsspace.com?ref=link',
            to: '391793380398',
            //description: 'Testing property links, and action links via Feed Dialog Javascript SDK',
            //picture: 'https://shawnsspace.com/ShawnsSpace.toon.nocolor..png',
            //properties: [{ text: 'Link Test 1', href: 'http://shawnsspace.com?ref=1'},
                            //{ text: 'Link Test 2', href: 'http://shawnsspace.com?ref=2'},
                            //{ text: 'Link Test 3', href: 'http://shawnsspace.com?ref=3'},
                            //{ text: 'Link Test 4', href: 'http://shawnsspace.com?ref=4'}
                            //],
            actions: [
            { name: 'Shawn', link: 'http://ShawnsSpace.com'}
            ]       
            });
            };
</javascript>
```